# Get customer id_default_group in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need to check customer id_default_group in TPL File.

Like

```
{$cookie->customer_firstname}
```

But this code

```
{$cookie->id_default_group}
```

doesn't work!

How can I get the ID Group when customer logins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***php***

Try this

```
$this->context->customer->id_default_group; // your variable to be used
```

or

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->customer->id_default_group; // your variable to be used
```

***.tpl***

If you want use it in `.tpl` first of all you need to pass your variable to your template file writing in `php`.

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'customer' => $this->context->customer
));
```

Then use it in `.tpl`

```
{if isset($customer->id_default_group)}
    {$customer->id_default_group|intval}
{/if}
```

Comment: I Want Use In TPL File .. Like {$cookie->customer_firstname}

Answer (score 1):

In PS 1.6.15 I use

```
{Group::getCurrent()->id}
```

Maybe this will work for you too.